# proving or disproving a claim about sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say $\left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right)$ does not converge and we know that $a_n$ is convergent, then $b_n$ is not convergent.

So i think that the claim is not true but I'm not sure on how to prove it.

I thought about proof of negation by saying that let's assume that $b_n$ is convergent and get to a situation where $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ does not converge.

Say $a_n$ converges to $5$ (random number), $b_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$
then $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ does not converge.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Have you proven that if $a_n \to K$ and $b_n \to M \ne 0$ then $\frac {a_n}{b_n} \to \frac KM$ yet?  If so, this is a straightforward prove by contradiction.  If $b_n$ converged to a non-zero value then $\frac {a_n}{b_n}$ would converge.  But it doesn't. So either $b_n$ does not converge or it converges to $0$.  But if it converged to $0$ then $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to \infty$ and doesn't converge. But it does.  So $b_n$ converges to a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $a_{n}=5$ and $b_{n}=n/(n+1)$, then $a_{n}/b_{n}\rightarrow 5$, so this is not a counterexample.

But if you let $a_{n}=1$ and $b_{n}=1/n$, then $a_{n}/b_{n}=n$ which does not converge.

Comment: whoops.. thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to disprove a conjecture is to find a counter example.

$a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ both converge to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=n$.